# Dask SSH-Cluster "no module named xxxx" error

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, pythonpath, dask-ssh

I am using Dask SSH-Cluster to setup a cluster. When I try to submit a task on the local machine and receive its response I get the following error:

```
.....
  File "/home/rohan/Desktop/BA/DistributedSetup/routers/main_router.py", line 36, in start_dask
    x = res.result()
  File "/home/rohan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 220, in result
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/rohan/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py", line 75, in loads
    return pickle.loads(x)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

It seems that dask does not find the modules (other files) I use in my project. I am assuming that this has something to do with the pythonpath but am not exactly sure how to go about fixing it. `utils` in the following code is an other file (module) in my project. The code that I use to reproduce the error:

```py
from utils import helper

def run_algo_dask():
    return "abc"


SSHCluster(hosts=['localhost', 'localhost'],
           connect_options=[{'username': 'rohan'}, {'username': 'rohan'}],
           worker_options={
               "nprocs": 1,
               "nthreads": 1
           }, 
           remote_python=["/home/rohan/.pyenv/shims/python3", "/home/rohan/.pyenv/shims/python3"])

client = Client(cluster)
helper()
res = client.submit(run_algo_dask)
x = res.result()
```